# Set precision for all big decimals in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, precision

Is there any way of defining a precision for all the BigDecimal numbers in Ruby or Ruby on Rails?

I setted the precision using the [limit](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html) method, but that didn't seem to work out:

```
irb(main):003:0> BigDecimal.limit
=> 25

irb(main):004:0> num = '0.' + 0.to_s * 30 + '1'
=> "0.0000000000000000000000000000001"

irb(main):005:0> decimal = BigDecimal(num)
=> #<BigDecimal:9614780,'0.1E-30',9(45)>

irb(main):006:0> puts decimal.to_s
0.0000000000000000000000000000001
=> nil

irb(main):007:0> BigDecimal.limit
=> 25
```

Did I misunderstand the usage of the `limit` method? Is there any other that can achieve what I want?

The app uses Ruby `2.3.4` and Rails `4.2.8`

Disclaimer: I already know how to truncate and how to only set the precision for individual values. I really need a way to set this "globally" (I mean, for all the new Big Decimals I instantiate or manipulate).

Comment: What do you mean by *"global fashion"*?

Comment: `limit` is low precedence and does not seem to directly correlate to the number stored. This is because *"The limit specified by this method takes less priority over any limit specified to instance methods such as ceil, floor, truncate, or round."* [Docs](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.5/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html#method-c-limit) this allows the "limit" to be 1 but you can round out to as many digits as you'd like

Comment: @Pavan I'd like to define the precision somewhere and ensure it's the same across all of the app .For example: if I get/instantiate a new BigDecimal from a request, I'd like to work with a smaller precision even before persisting it on the DB

Comment: Again from the documentation of `BigDecimal::new` *"The actual number of significant digits used in computation is usually larger than the specified number."*

Comment: @engineersmnky Sorry, but I can't understand what this docs mean. Can you please illustrate with example?

Comment: Docs are stating that a) limit has very little impact on actual number stored b) a specified limit will not necessarily impact how computation works. I am assuming you need for a fixed precision has to do with computation and I am informing you it will not work this way. Simple  example `(BigDecimal("1",1) * BigDecimal("0.0001",1) ).to_f  #=> 0.0001` notice the limit is set to `1` significant digit in each case yet the result has `4` significant digits

Comment: Got it! Thanks @engineersmnky

Answer (score -1):

You can try

```
 2.1.7 :056 > num = '0.' + 0.to_s * 30 + '1'
 => "0.0000000000000000000000000000001" 
2.1.7 :057 > decimal = BigDecimal(num)
 => #<BigDecimal:7be2178,'0.1E-30',9(45)> 
2.1.7 :058 > puts decimal.to_s
0.0000000000000000000000000000001
 => nil 
2.1.7 :059 > '%.2f' % decimal
 => "0.00"
```

Comment: I need a  way to set for all BigDecimals, not just one at a time :(. Sorry.

Comment: If this is for a column in the db, you can try setting it in the migration.
decimal, :precision => 5, :scale => 2

Also try http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html